# to PGFplot addplot3(+) discrete data -> smooth surface

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, axis

I'm using Xualatex on Texlive with PGFplot 1.13 and I want to smoothly plot a discrete surface, something like this (just to illustrate, this is not my problem).

[image]

My code and my data:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

  \begin{document}


  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[]
  \addplot3[surf] 
  table [] {
  %%% DISCRETE X Y Z DATA %%%
  };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

[You'll find the code with the complete table here.](https://pastebin.com/UbrVRr6S)

The result is:

[image: Plotresult]

I get basically a line through all points. What I want: I want a surface, that is to say, an interpolation of the surface between the data points. How do I do this? I found the addplot3, `shader=interp`-option, but this doesn't work here but results in

> Package pgfplots Error: CRITICAL: shader=interp: got unsupported pdf shading type '0'. This may corrupt your pdf!. \end{axis}

The pgfmanual is mostly about continous function plot, and the solutions that I found on the web were solutions for DATA discrete data matrices and not for a list of data.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess it could about the data points of your data? It would be good to provide a small exemplary data file... I think that you always need data matrices (written in a list), but it might be possible to "shape" your data appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the link to the table..

Comment: Oh, I see the problem: the sampling in the second row always has to be the same (changing the step width is no problem, but the number of data points must be the same so that a matrix can be constructed)

Answer (score 2):

The table has to be transformable into a matrix, therefore it requires always equal number of sampling points (in this smaller example 3x4)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot3[surf,mesh/rows=4,shader=interp] 
            table [] {
-100    0                       0.890242
-100    5                       0.891759
-100    10                      0.891854
-97.5   0                       0.0472445
-97.5   5                       0.0464595
-97.5   10                      0.0465202
-95 0                       -0.113663
-95 5                       -0.114502
-95 10                      -0.114424
-92.5   0                       0.227895
-92.5   5                       0.229116
-92.5   10                      0.229294

        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

## EDIT

Now a plot with the almost complete data set.
I just threw away the points on the finer (2.5 stepwidth) grid to ensure that each value in the 1st row has the same number of points in the second row.
Also note that `mesh/cols=21` is update according to the data set size and i added `z buffer = sort` for a correct depth information in the plot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot3[surf,mesh/cols=21,shader=interp,z buffer=sort,colormap/viridis] 
            table []
            {-100   0                       0.890242
-100    5                       0.891759
-100    10                      0.891854
-100    15                      0.891187
-100    20                      0.891288
-100    25                      0.891627
-100    30                      0.89161
-100    35                      0.889975
-100    40                      0.891411
-100    45                      0.891342
-100    50                      0.890376
-100    55                      0.8908
-100    60                      0.891042
-100    65                      0.891422
-100    70                      0.890359
-100    75                      0.892868
-100    80                      0.894885
-100    85                      0.896399
-100    90                      0.903371
-100    95                      0.895422
-100    100                     0.789038
-95 0                       -0.113663
-95 5                       -0.114502
-95 10                      -0.114424
-95 15                      -0.114218
-95 20                      -0.114142
-95 25                      -0.114514
-95 30                      -0.114592
-95 35                      -0.113424
-95 40                      -0.114547
-95 45                      -0.114289
-95 50                      -0.113987
-95 55                      -0.113841
-95 60                      -0.114299
-95 65                      -0.114445
-95 70                      -0.113315
-95 75                      -0.115157
-95 80                      -0.116474
-95 85                      -0.119704
-95 90                      -0.124744
-95 95                      -0.125946
-95 100                     -0.0910245
-90 0                       -0.153883
-90 5                       -0.154824
-90 10                      -0.154834
-90 15                      -0.154443
-90 20                      -0.154291
-90 25                      -0.154848
-90 30                      -0.154812
-90 35                      -0.153392
-90 40                      -0.154674
-90 45                      -0.154394
-90 50                      -0.154004
-90 55                      -0.153643
-90 60                      -0.154539
-90 65                      -0.154699
-90 70                      -0.153451
-90 75                      -0.15615
-90 80                      -0.157962
-90 85                      -0.162141
-90 90                      -0.161701
-90 95                      -0.161825
-90 100                     -0.130185
-85 0                       0.00912283
-85 5                       0.0101553
-85 10                      0.0101936
-85 15                      0.00971271
-85 20                      0.00977144
-85 25                      0.01032
-85 30                      0.0103496
-85 35                      0.0096031
-85 40                      0.0104384
-85 45                      0.010801
-85 50                      0.0102221
-85 55                      0.0104293
-85 60                      0.0106782
-85 65                      0.0102876
-85 70                      0.00850681
-85 75                      0.00743402
-85 80                      0.0048742
-85 85                      0.000298269
-85 90                      0.00068327
-85 95                      0.0104809
-85 100                     0.0338374
-80 0                       0.039272
-80 5                       0.0394088
-80 10                      0.0394886
-80 15                      0.0393642
-80 20                      0.0394712
-80 25                      0.0396478
-80 30                      0.0396488
-80 35                      0.0398504
-80 40                      0.0398055
-80 45                      0.0401175
-80 50                      0.0399814
-80 55                      0.0399929
-80 60                      0.039754
-80 65                      0.0390279
-80 70                      0.0380515
-80 75                      0.036015
-80 80                      0.0336199
-80 85                      0.0309498
-80 90                      0.0328582
-80 95                      0.0428488
-80 100                     0.0602838
-75 0                       0.0622751
-75 5                       0.0618247
-75 10                      0.0618694
-75 15                      0.062187
-75 20                      0.0622391
-75 25                      0.0620305
-75 30                      0.0622043
-75 35                      0.0628393
-75 40                      0.0622727
-75 45                      0.0625394
-75 50                      0.0625974
-75 55                      0.0627189
-75 60                      0.0619139
-75 65                      0.0613664
-75 70                      0.0606612
-75 75                      0.0581718
-75 80                      0.05638
-75 85                      0.0544441
-75 90                      0.0572797
-75 95                      0.0668457
-75 100                     0.0801762
-70 0                       0.0645191
-70 5                       0.0646034
-70 10                      0.0646341
-70 15                      0.0646918
-70 20                      0.0648443
-70 25                      0.0648074
-70 30                      0.0649239
-70 35                      0.0651508
-70 40                      0.0650559
-70 45                      0.0652394
-70 50                      0.0651299
-70 55                      0.0651387
-70 60                      0.0644883
-70 65                      0.0637946
-70 70                      0.0628513
-70 75                      0.0611306
-70 80                      0.0595632
-70 85                      0.058235
-70 90                      0.060668
-70 95                      0.0696308
-70 100                     0.0790782
-65 0                       0.064869
-65 5                       0.0649853
-65 10                      0.065092
-65 15                      0.0651028
-65 20                      0.0653063
-65 25                      0.0653267
-65 30                      0.0652692
-65 35                      0.0654794
-65 40                      0.0654436
-65 45                      0.0656237
-65 50                      0.065499
-65 55                      0.0654945
-65 60                      0.0649111
-65 65                      0.0640349
-65 70                      0.0632004
-65 75                      0.0618811
-65 80                      0.0604164
-65 85                      0.0594519
-65 90                      0.0616514
-65 95                      0.069209
-65 100                     0.0777868
-60 0                       0.0521012
-60 5                       0.0519069
-60 10                      0.0519221
-60 15                      0.0520155
-60 20                      0.0521632
-60 25                      0.0520775
-60 30                      0.0522229
-60 35                      0.0527261
-60 40                      0.0523243
-60 45                      0.0524736
-60 50                      0.0523714
-60 55                      0.0523741
-60 60                      0.0515217
-60 65                      0.0510051
-60 70                      0.0507322
-60 75                      0.0488871
-60 80                      0.0477937
-60 85                      0.0467088
-60 90                      0.0482752
-60 95                      0.0551092
-60 100                     0.0633594
-55 0                       0.0445773
-55 5                       0.0444265
-55 10                      0.0444374
-55 15                      0.044451
-55 20                      0.0446589
-55 25                      0.0445716
-55 30                      0.044669
-55 35                      0.0451928
-55 40                      0.0448067
-55 45                      0.0449068
-55 50                      0.0447231
-55 55                      0.0448177
-55 60                      0.0440015
-55 65                      0.0433819
-55 70                      0.043338
-55 75                      0.0416083
-55 80                      0.0405917
-55 85                      0.0394043
-55 90                      0.0406738
-55 95                      0.0468451
-55 100                     0.0544926
-50 0                       0.0385063
-50 5                       0.0387616
-50 10                      0.038835
-50 15                      0.0387826
-50 20                      0.0387964
-50 25                      0.039051
-50 30                      0.0390817
-50 35                      0.0389553
-50 40                      0.0390997
-50 45                      0.0392247
-50 50                      0.0390029
-50 55                      0.0387386
-50 60                      0.0385911
-50 65                      0.0380272
-50 70                      0.0369711
-50 75                      0.0361371
-50 80                      0.0350073
-50 85                      0.0339582
-50 90                      0.0348838
-50 95                      0.0405394
-50 100                     0.0483927
-45 0                       0.0319868
-45 5                       0.0320539
-45 10                      0.0320857
-45 15                      0.0320946
-45 20                      0.0321906
-45 25                      0.032244
-45 30                      0.0322991
-45 35                      0.0324237
-45 40                      0.0323291
-45 45                      0.032425
-45 50                      0.0322518
-45 55                      0.0321145
-45 60                      0.0317483
-45 65                      0.0312053
-45 70                      0.0305852
-45 75                      0.0295309
-45 80                      0.0284939
-45 85                      0.0275173
-45 90                      0.0281629
-45 95                      0.033167
-45 100                     0.0398894
-40 0                       0.0274829
-40 5                       0.0274908
-40 10                      0.0275393
-40 15                      0.027577
-40 20                      0.0275702
-40 25                      0.0276695
-40 30                      0.0277726
-40 35                      0.0277929
-40 40                      0.0277193
-40 45                      0.0277977
-40 50                      0.0275554
-40 55                      0.0274914
-40 60                      0.027154
-40 65                      0.026782
-40 70                      0.0260139
-40 75                      0.0250202
-40 80                      0.0241737
-40 85                      0.0228488
-40 90                      0.0238491
-40 95                      0.0281195
-40 100                     0.0349745
-35 0                       0.0230801
-35 5                       0.0230516
-35 10                      0.0230804
-35 15                      0.023145
-35 20                      0.0232265
-35 25                      0.0231808
-35 30                      0.0232302
-35 35                      0.0233941
-35 40                      0.0232351
-35 45                      0.023285
-35 50                      0.0231809
-35 55                      0.023092
-35 60                      0.022656
-35 65                      0.0222403
-35 70                      0.0217801
-35 75                      0.0208057
-35 80                      0.0199439
-35 85                      0.0190505
-35 90                      0.019606
-35 95                      0.0233013
-35 100                     0.0285802
-30 0                       0.0206402
-30 5                       0.0203142
-30 10                      0.0203473
-30 15                      0.0205433
-30 20                      0.0206759
-30 25                      0.0204423
-30 30                      0.0204086
-30 35                      0.0209167
-30 40                      0.0204581
-30 45                      0.0205004
-30 50                      0.0206073
-30 55                      0.0205024
-30 60                      0.0199296
-30 65                      0.0194584
-30 70                      0.0194772
-30 75                      0.0183544
-30 80                      0.0175017
-30 85                      0.0170997
-30 90                      0.0174029
-30 95                      0.0202895
-30 100                     0.0249889
-25 0                       0.0139628
-25 5                       0.014102
-25 10                      0.0141115
-25 15                      0.0140401
-25 20                      0.0141183
-25 25                      0.0141627
-25 30                      0.0142119
-25 35                      0.0141946
-25 40                      0.0142221
-25 45                      0.0142393
-25 50                      0.0140314
-25 55                      0.0140538
-25 60                      0.0136485
-25 65                      0.0133743
-25 70                      0.0130107
-25 75                      0.0122952
-25 80                      0.0116699
-25 85                      0.0108161
-25 90                      0.0112173
-25 95                      0.0138145
-25 100                     0.0182726
-20 0                       0.0105885
-20 5                       0.0107151
-20 10                      0.0107178
-20 15                      0.0106144
-20 20                      0.0107609
-20 25                      0.0107375
-20 30                      0.0107522
-20 35                      0.0108191
-20 40                      0.0108049
-20 45                      0.0108068
-20 50                      0.0105874
-20 55                      0.0107299
-20 60                      0.0102992
-20 65                      0.00996492
-20 70                      0.00988069
-20 75                      0.00921709
-20 80                      0.00872713
-20 85                      0.00795466
-20 90                      0.00828872
-20 95                      0.010448
-20 100                     0.0138676
-15 0                       0.008931
-15 5                       0.00891326
-15 10                      0.00894475
-15 15                      0.0089947
-15 20                      0.00892287
-15 25                      0.00902571
-15 30                      0.0090292
-15 35                      0.00899974
-15 40                      0.0089735
-15 45                      0.00900627
-15 50                      0.0089863
-15 55                      0.00872863
-15 60                      0.00877918
-15 65                      0.00859593
-15 70                      0.00809283
-15 75                      0.00779015
-15 80                      0.00731463
-15 85                      0.00700118
-15 90                      0.00706672
-15 95                      0.00873308
-15 100                     0.0118705
-10 0                       0.00556712
-10 5                       0.00564638
-10 10                      0.00564453
-10 15                      0.00561828
-10 20                      0.00563384
-10 25                      0.00568475
-10 30                      0.00568739
-10 35                      0.00563811
-10 40                      0.00568113
-10 45                      0.00568391
-10 50                      0.00560133
-10 55                      0.00551431
-10 60                      0.0055277
-10 65                      0.00533903
-10 70                      0.00503378
-10 75                      0.00488871
-10 80                      0.00454932
-10 85                      0.00427259
-10 90                      0.00431207
-10 95                      0.00552837
-10 100                     0.00715035
-5  0                       0.00357331
-5  5                       0.00340655
-5  10                      0.00343857
-5  15                      0.00354074
-5  20                      0.0034475
-5  25                      0.00345455
-5  30                      0.00350679
-5  35                      0.00357505
-5  40                      0.00340554
-5  45                      0.0034489
-5  50                      0.00347615
-5  55                      0.00340327
-5  60                      0.00337427
-5  65                      0.003396
-5  70                      0.00326812
-5  75                      0.00292378
-5  80                      0.00292057
-5  85                      0.00267006
-5  90                      0.00289266
-5  95                      0.00344394
-5  100                     0.00454422
0   0                       -0.00912383
0   5                       -0.00875956
0   10                      -0.00882539
0   15                      -0.00911983
0   20                      -0.00861476
0   25                      -0.00902569
0   30                      -0.00907842
0   35                      -0.00888248
0   40                      -0.00881594
0   45                      -0.00880447
0   50                      -0.00908106
0   55                      -0.00867053
0   60                      -0.00923458
0   65                      -0.00950475
0   70                      -0.00895749
0   75                      -0.00890865
0   80                      -0.00881627
0   85                      -0.00929848
0   90                      -0.00959197
0   95                      -0.0101012
0   100                     -0.0102158

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

## EDIT 2

It is of course possible to add more x values, which might be want you want do do. But they still need the same `y` sampling as before...

An example with a bit more of your data. (Additional points e.g. at x=-97.5, ...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={5}{20}]
        \addplot3[surf,mesh/cols=21,mesh/ordering=x varies, shader=interp,colormap/viridis,z buffer = sort,join=round] 
            table []
            {-100   0                       0.890242
-100    5                       0.891759
-100    10                      0.891854
-100    15                      0.891187
-100    20                      0.891288
-100    25                      0.891627
-100    30                      0.89161
-100    35                      0.889975
-100    40                      0.891411
-100    45                      0.891342
-100    50                      0.890376
-100    55                      0.8908
-100    60                      0.891042
-100    65                      0.891422
-100    70                      0.890359
-100    75                      0.892868
-100    80                      0.894885
-100    85                      0.896399
-100    90                      0.903371
-100    95                      0.895422
-100    100                     0.789038
    -97.5   0                       0.0472445
    -97.5   5                       0.0464595
    -97.5   10                      0.0465202
    -97.5   15                      0.0467339
    -97.5   20                      0.046771
    -97.5   25                      0.0463781
    -97.5   30                      0.0462845
    -97.5   35                      0.0473997
    -97.5   40                      0.0463126
    -97.5   45                      0.0464037
    -97.5   50                      0.0466736
    -97.5   55                      0.0466961
    -97.5   60                      0.0461123
    -97.5   65                      0.0461535
    -97.5   70                      0.0477886
    -97.5   75                      0.0469181
    -97.5   80                      0.0476309
    -97.5   85                      0.0471997
    -97.5   90                      0.050453
    -97.5   95                      0.0409994
    -97.5   100                     0.0274539
-95 0                       -0.113663
-95 5                       -0.114502
-95 10                      -0.114424
-95 15                      -0.114218
-95 20                      -0.114142
-95 25                      -0.114514
-95 30                      -0.114592
-95 35                      -0.113424
-95 40                      -0.114547
-95 45                      -0.114289
-95 50                      -0.113987
-95 55                      -0.113841
-95 60                      -0.114299
-95 65                      -0.114445
-95 70                      -0.113315
-95 75                      -0.115157
-95 80                      -0.116474
-95 85                      -0.119704
-95 90                      -0.124744
-95 95                      -0.125946
-95 100                     -0.0910245
-90 0                       -0.153883
-90 5                       -0.154824
-90 10                      -0.154834
-90 15                      -0.154443
-90 20                      -0.154291
-90 25                      -0.154848
-90 30                      -0.154812
-90 35                      -0.153392
-90 40                      -0.154674
-90 45                      -0.154394
-90 50                      -0.154004
-90 55                      -0.153643
-90 60                      -0.154539
-90 65                      -0.154699
-90 70                      -0.153451
-90 75                      -0.15615
-90 80                      -0.157962
-90 85                      -0.162141
-90 90                      -0.161701
-90 95                      -0.161825
-90 100                     -0.130185
    -87.5   0                       0.0702012
    -87.5   5                       0.0698165
    -87.5   10                      0.0697102
    -87.5   15                      0.0699685
    -87.5   20                      0.0700177
    -87.5   25                      0.0697628
    -87.5   30                      0.0699044
    -87.5   35                      0.0706515
    -87.5   40                      0.070021
    -87.5   45                      0.070117
    -87.5   50                      0.0705476
    -87.5   55                      0.0704744
    -87.5   60                      0.0700972
    -87.5   65                      0.0698478
    -87.5   70                      0.0698847
    -87.5   75                      0.067667
    -87.5   80                      0.064931
    -87.5   85                      0.0615626
    -87.5   90                      0.0604824
    -87.5   95                      0.0663312
    -87.5   100                     0.0852354
-85 0                       0.00912283
-85 5                       0.0101553
-85 10                      0.0101936
-85 15                      0.00971271
-85 20                      0.00977144
-85 25                      0.01032
-85 30                      0.0103496
-85 35                      0.0096031
-85 40                      0.0104384
-85 45                      0.010801
-85 50                      0.0102221
-85 55                      0.0104293
-85 60                      0.0106782
-85 65                      0.0102876
-85 70                      0.00850681
-85 75                      0.00743402
-85 80                      0.0048742
-85 85                      0.000298269
-85 90                      0.00068327
-85 95                      0.0104809
-85 100                     0.0338374
    -82.5   0                       0.0603545
    -82.5   5                       0.0597912
    -82.5   10                      0.0598671
    -82.5   15                      0.0601708
    -82.5   20                      0.0603278
    -82.5   25                      0.0599969
    -82.5   30                      0.0600116
    -82.5   35                      0.0608373
    -82.5   40                      0.0601616
    -82.5   45                      0.0604566
    -82.5   50                      0.0606274
    -82.5   55                      0.0610388
    -82.5   60                      0.0601314
    -82.5   65                      0.059579
    -82.5   70                      0.0594379
    -82.5   75                      0.0567261
    -82.5   80                      0.0541166
    -82.5   85                      0.0510373
    -82.5   90                      0.052505
    -82.5   95                      0.0617971
    -82.5   100                     0.0807216
-80 0                       0.039272
-80 5                       0.0394088
-80 10                      0.0394886
-80 15                      0.0393642
-80 20                      0.0394712
-80 25                      0.0396478
-80 30                      0.0396488
-80 35                      0.0398504
-80 40                      0.0398055
-80 45                      0.0401175
-80 50                      0.0399814
-80 55                      0.0399929
-80 60                      0.039754
-80 65                      0.0390279
-80 70                      0.0380515
-80 75                      0.036015
-80 80                      0.0336199
-80 85                      0.0309498
-80 90                      0.0328582
-80 95                      0.0428488
-80 100                     0.0602838
    -77.5   0                       0.0312866
    -77.5   5                       0.0315573
    -77.5   10                      0.0315928
    -77.5   15                      0.0314655
    -77.5   20                      0.0315329
    -77.5   25                      0.0317495
    -77.5   30                      0.0318559
    -77.5   35                      0.0318683
    -77.5   40                      0.0319875
    -77.5   45                      0.0322524
    -77.5   50                      0.0320216
    -77.5   55                      0.0320503
    -77.5   60                      0.031659
    -77.5   65                      0.0310816
    -77.5   70                      0.029935
    -77.5   75                      0.0279992
    -77.5   80                      0.025887
    -77.5   85                      0.0235086
    -77.5   90                      0.025888
    -77.5   95                      0.0356641
    -77.5   100                     0.0513903
-75 0                       0.0622751
-75 5                       0.0618247
-75 10                      0.0618694
-75 15                      0.062187
-75 20                      0.0622391
-75 25                      0.0620305
-75 30                      0.0622043
-75 35                      0.0628393
-75 40                      0.0622727
-75 45                      0.0625394
-75 50                      0.0625974
-75 55                      0.0627189
-75 60                      0.0619139
-75 65                      0.0613664
-75 70                      0.0606612
-75 75                      0.0581718
-75 80                      0.05638
-75 85                      0.0544441
-75 90                      0.0572797
-75 95                      0.0668457
-75 100                     0.0801762
    -72.5   0                       0.0298162
    -72.5   5                       0.0298861
    -72.5   10                      0.0300149
    -72.5   15                      0.02986
    -72.5   20                      0.0301774
    -72.5   25                      0.0301335
    -72.5   30                      0.0300849
    -72.5   35                      0.0306007
    -72.5   40                      0.0303007
    -72.5   45                      0.0306575
    -72.5   50                      0.0304066
    -72.5   55                      0.0304834
    -72.5   60                      0.0299733
    -72.5   65                      0.0289518
    -72.5   70                      0.0283574
    -72.5   75                      0.0263678
    -72.5   80                      0.0249127
    -72.5   85                      0.0230265
    -72.5   90                      0.0255419
    -72.5   95                      0.034722
    -72.5   100                     0.0483058
-70 0                       0.0645191
-70 5                       0.0646034
-70 10                      0.0646341
-70 15                      0.0646918
-70 20                      0.0648443
-70 25                      0.0648074
-70 30                      0.0649239
-70 35                      0.0651508
-70 40                      0.0650559
-70 45                      0.0652394
-70 50                      0.0651299
-70 55                      0.0651387
-70 60                      0.0644883
-70 65                      0.0637946
-70 70                      0.0628513
-70 75                      0.0611306
-70 80                      0.0595632
-70 85                      0.058235
-70 90                      0.060668
-70 95                      0.0696308
-70 100                     0.0790782
    -67.5   0                       0.0213028
    -67.5   5                       0.021295
    -67.5   10                      0.0212158
    -67.5   15                      0.0214484
    -67.5   20                      0.0213959
    -67.5   25                      0.0214623
    -67.5   30                      0.0217339
    -67.5   35                      0.0218086
    -67.5   40                      0.0217866
    -67.5   45                      0.021831
    -67.5   50                      0.0218412
    -67.5   55                      0.0217389
    -67.5   60                      0.0210355
    -67.5   65                      0.0206623
    -67.5   70                      0.0196391
    -67.5   75                      0.0179629
    -67.5   80                      0.0162991
    -67.5   85                      0.0152854
    -67.5   90                      0.0177912
    -67.5   95                      0.0249828
    -67.5   100                     0.0385412
-65 0                       0.064869
-65 5                       0.0649853
-65 10                      0.065092
-65 15                      0.0651028
-65 20                      0.0653063
-65 25                      0.0653267
-65 30                      0.0652692
-65 35                      0.0654794
-65 40                      0.0654436
-65 45                      0.0656237
-65 50                      0.065499
-65 55                      0.0654945
-65 60                      0.0649111
-65 65                      0.0640349
-65 70                      0.0632004
-65 75                      0.0618811
-65 80                      0.0604164
-65 85                      0.0594519
-65 90                      0.0616514
-65 95                      0.069209
-65 100                     0.0777868
-60 0                       0.0521012
-60 5                       0.0519069
-60 10                      0.0519221
-60 15                      0.0520155
-60 20                      0.0521632
-60 25                      0.0520775
-60 30                      0.0522229
-60 35                      0.0527261
-60 40                      0.0523243
-60 45                      0.0524736
-60 50                      0.0523714
-60 55                      0.0523741
-60 60                      0.0515217
-60 65                      0.0510051
-60 70                      0.0507322
-60 75                      0.0488871
-60 80                      0.0477937
-60 85                      0.0467088
-60 90                      0.0482752
-60 95                      0.0551092
-60 100                     0.0633594
-55 0                       0.0445773
-55 5                       0.0444265
-55 10                      0.0444374
-55 15                      0.044451
-55 20                      0.0446589
-55 25                      0.0445716
-55 30                      0.044669
-55 35                      0.0451928
-55 40                      0.0448067
-55 45                      0.0449068
-55 50                      0.0447231
-55 55                      0.0448177
-55 60                      0.0440015
-55 65                      0.0433819
-55 70                      0.043338
-55 75                      0.0416083
-55 80                      0.0405917
-55 85                      0.0394043
-55 90                      0.0406738
-55 95                      0.0468451
-55 100                     0.0544926
-50 0                       0.0385063
-50 5                       0.0387616
-50 10                      0.038835
-50 15                      0.0387826
-50 20                      0.0387964
-50 25                      0.039051
-50 30                      0.0390817
-50 35                      0.0389553
-50 40                      0.0390997
-50 45                      0.0392247
-50 50                      0.0390029
-50 55                      0.0387386
-50 60                      0.0385911
-50 65                      0.0380272
-50 70                      0.0369711
-50 75                      0.0361371
-50 80                      0.0350073
-50 85                      0.0339582
-50 90                      0.0348838
-50 95                      0.0405394
-50 100                     0.0483927
-45 0                       0.0319868
-45 5                       0.0320539
-45 10                      0.0320857
-45 15                      0.0320946
-45 20                      0.0321906
-45 25                      0.032244
-45 30                      0.0322991
-45 35                      0.0324237
-45 40                      0.0323291
-45 45                      0.032425
-45 50                      0.0322518
-45 55                      0.0321145
-45 60                      0.0317483
-45 65                      0.0312053
-45 70                      0.0305852
-45 75                      0.0295309
-45 80                      0.0284939
-45 85                      0.0275173
-45 90                      0.0281629
-45 95                      0.033167
-45 100                     0.0398894
-40 0                       0.0274829
-40 5                       0.0274908
-40 10                      0.0275393
-40 15                      0.027577
-40 20                      0.0275702
-40 25                      0.0276695
-40 30                      0.0277726
-40 35                      0.0277929
-40 40                      0.0277193
-40 45                      0.0277977
-40 50                      0.0275554
-40 55                      0.0274914
-40 60                      0.027154
-40 65                      0.026782
-40 70                      0.0260139
-40 75                      0.0250202
-40 80                      0.0241737
-40 85                      0.0228488
-40 90                      0.0238491
-40 95                      0.0281195
-40 100                     0.0349745
-35 0                       0.0230801
-35 5                       0.0230516
-35 10                      0.0230804
-35 15                      0.023145
-35 20                      0.0232265
-35 25                      0.0231808
-35 30                      0.0232302
-35 35                      0.0233941
-35 40                      0.0232351
-35 45                      0.023285
-35 50                      0.0231809
-35 55                      0.023092
-35 60                      0.022656
-35 65                      0.0222403
-35 70                      0.0217801
-35 75                      0.0208057
-35 80                      0.0199439
-35 85                      0.0190505
-35 90                      0.019606
-35 95                      0.0233013
-35 100                     0.0285802
-30 0                       0.0206402
-30 5                       0.0203142
-30 10                      0.0203473
-30 15                      0.0205433
-30 20                      0.0206759
-30 25                      0.0204423
-30 30                      0.0204086
-30 35                      0.0209167
-30 40                      0.0204581
-30 45                      0.0205004
-30 50                      0.0206073
-30 55                      0.0205024
-30 60                      0.0199296
-30 65                      0.0194584
-30 70                      0.0194772
-30 75                      0.0183544
-30 80                      0.0175017
-30 85                      0.0170997
-30 90                      0.0174029
-30 95                      0.0202895
-30 100                     0.0249889

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is not really working for me. If I do that for the complete data (multiple of 3 entries), this gives an ugly result far away from the real surface. http://pasteboard.co/1n0uFWt6P.png

I think that this is a result of the non-ordered data and a non-fitting sample size.

Isn't there a better way to do this? A way that does neither rely on a exact multiple of a number nor on the order of the data?

Comment: @J.Doe  If you want to plot your example data, you always need to have the exact same number of 2nd-row-points for each 1st-row-point. They do not need to be on a regular grid, however...

Comment: I took your input file and threw away all the 2.5 steps, so that the data only contains steps of 5. See the edit for a plot result.

Comment: @J.Doe See the second edit for at least a bit irregular data points. Could be sufficient for you...